# Why Can't I get the data-div working in this navigation menu in a WordPress theme using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm having a very difficult time getting a navigation working [on this site](https://kennetteagleshockey.com) which is a WordPress site using a Bootstrap starter theme. I inherited the site and would like to get the navigation working correctly asap.

The code for the nav block;

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/"><img id="nav-logo" class="logo" src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/images/eagle.png" alt="Kennett Eagles Logo - An eagle bursting through with the word Eagles above talons." /></a>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="hamburger hamburger--elastic-r navbar-toggle collapsed hide" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" aria-label="Menu">
          <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
          </span>
        </button>

        <a id="mobile-logo" class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img class="logo" src="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/images/eagle.png"/></a>

      </div>

      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
                'menu' => 'Main Menu',
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'items_wrap' => '<li>%3$s</li>', 
                'menu_class' => 'scroll-to-div',
                'container' => false
            ) ); ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

The code for the JS the menu uses; It's just a piece of the huge JS file [that you can view here.](https://kennetteagleshockey.com/js/script.js)

```
$(function () {
  function t(t) {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: t.offset().top - 100
    }, 0)
  }
  $("#mobile-logo").is(":visible") && $("#navbar a").on("click", function (t) {
    $(".hamburger-box").click()
  }), "" !== window.location.hash && t($(window.location.hash.replace("nav-", ""))), $("#navbar a, .scroll-to-div").on("click", function (e) {
    "/" === window.location.pathname && (e.preventDefault(), location.hash = $(this).data("div"), t($("#" + $(this).data("div"))), $("#navbar li").removeClass("active"), $(this).parent().addClass("active"), location.hash.replace("#", ""))
  })
})
```

and the functions.php file, the block of code I am using where I am trying to get the `data-div` to go into the a tag, but call the correct page that corresponds with the correct menu item.

```
/*
 * Add scroll-to-div class to main navigation <a> links and data-div for the jump to.
 */
function add_menuclass($ulclass) {
    return preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="scroll-to-div"' . 'data-div="<?php get_page($id); ?>"', $ulclass, 1);
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_menuclass');
```

What is my issue is that the navigation and everything works fine [on this development site here](https://six03.com/khspuck). That doesn't even have the `data-div` but everything works as it should.

The live site, does not. It throws an `TypeError t.offset(...) is undefined; can't access its "top" property.`

Answer (score 1):

So in the `functions.php` file, I had to split up the class I wanted to add to the navigation links and the placement of `data-div` in the `<a>` tag using `nav_menu_link_attributes`

```
/**
 * Add scroll-to-div class to main navigation <a> links.
 */
function add_menuclass($ulclass) {
    return preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="scroll-to-div"', $ulclass);
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_menuclass');

/**
 * Bootstrap modal trigger from a WordPress Menu item, the modal trigger requires an attribute of data-div
 * with a value of what page the code corresponds with. // About link.
 */
    add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'about_menu_attribute_add', 10, 3 );
    function about_menu_attribute_add( $atts, $item, $args )
    {
      // Set the menu ID
      $menu_link = 3622;
      // Conditionally match the ID and add the attribute and value
      if ($item->ID == $menu_link) {
        $atts['data-div'] = 'about';
      }
      //Return the new attribute
      return $atts;
    };
```

You have to place the ID of the page in the code, so I had to repeat the code four more times for each menu item. Sloppy perhaps, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve your entire problem, but it's at least part of it.

Your link HTML is coming out as this:
`<a class="scroll-to-div"data-div="<?php get_page($id); ?>" href="https://kennetteagleshockey.com/about/">About</a>` on the rendered page, due to syntax errors in your `add_menuclass` method.

Try changing

```
return preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="scroll-to-div"' . 'data-div="<?php get_page($id); ?>"', $ulclass, 1);
```

to

```
return preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="scroll-to-div" data-div="'.get_page($id).'"', $ulclass, 1);
```

Note that before, you had no space in the output between the `class` attribute and the `data-div` attribute, and that the PHP code was part of a string. The change above fixes these issues.

You may or may not still have issues with your javascript - but this will at least be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Your code I used and replaced the old line I had (thanks for pointing out the space issue) but I was unable to save your code;  `Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 55 of file wp-content/themes/wp-bootstrap-starter/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string`

Comment: I had thought the code I used worked. It did work for a couple clicks through, but now doesn't work I used `.$page->ID.` instead of `.get_page($id).` So I'm right back to where I started from trying to get the corresponding page in the `data-div` and the JavaScript figured out.